# Insert Into using Ajax in ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm woondring how to insert data into my DataBase using Ajax in ASP.net MVC. Exactly i want when user click on Add new item, a Popup is shown where user wil put some data And a `Ok` Onclick This will add the iserted Data and close this popup or show error Message.
I'm using `Data entity Framework`. And sorry for this Question but i'm biginner at ASP.net MVc and Ajax so Please any help or Tuto link that will be nice :)

Comment: I know just some help or exmple so i can get start :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at asp.net webapi which is built into asp.net MVC 4.

you don't have to use that, but it is a nice way to do Ajaxy stuff.  However, the basic idea is you GET/POST (using something like .post or .get in jquery) to an action  (basically a URL).   That action then takes care of storing things to a database.

You'll want to learn about model binding and json....  thats the ability for asp.mvc to convert your C# objects to and from JSON

You'll want to go and look at a number of asp.net mvc example apps, like nerd dinner, for examples of MVC and ajax.....

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at the [Microsoft ASP.Net MVC tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials).

They are very helpfull and I cannot write down a better solution then they did already ;-)